Requirements for an Alexander matrix to represent a knot diagram
Could there exist a finite set of requirements for an Alexander matrix such that if and only if these requirements are met, that the Alexander matrix represents a knot diagram.
For example, i am quite certain (i havent given a formal proof though) that if an Alexander matrix has two rows who are exactly the same, that it cant represent a knot.
If they do exist and have been found, could someone refer me to literature in which these are given

Could you say exactly what you mean by an Alexander matrix? It would be helpful having a source with the definition you're using.

I mean the (n, n+2) matrix you get when you follow the first steps given in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial, under ‘Computing the polynomial’

As far as I know, I don't think there is such a set of requirements. There are, however, some easy properties that you can check. For example, the Alexander polynomial of a knot is never $0$, so if the determinant of a matrix is $0$, then it can't be the Alexander matrix of any knot. Another easy check is that $\Delta(-1)$ is an odd integer for the Alexander polynomial $\Delta(t)$ of any knot. You can find other such properties in Livingston's Knot Theory.
